# How to access Laravel Singletons in a class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I have registered a singleton in a service provider like so:

```
$this->app->singleton(MyClass::class);
```

This can normally be accessed by simply stating it in the parameters like so:

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function index(MyClass $myClass)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

However I cannot seem to be able to access this singleton in other custom classes (i.e. non controller classes).  (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#resolving)

For example like here:

```
class Bar {
   private $myClass;
   private $a;
   private $b;

   public function __construct($a, $b) {
      $this->a = $a;
      $this->b = $b;
      $this->myClass = ... // TODO: get singleton
   }
}
```

How do I do this?

Note that I will be creating multiple instances of `Bar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In later Laravel versions 6 and higher there are even more helpers to solve this:

```
resolve(MyClass::class);
app(MyClass::class);
```

& all the methods provided by the other answers

```
class Bar {
   private $myClass;
   private $a;
   private $b;

   public function __construct($a, $b) {
      $this->a = $a;
      $this->b = $b;
      $this->myClass = app(MyClass::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: no difference, if you dive in the source code you will see that resolve() is just an alias for app()

Answer (score 10):

Type-hint the class/interface in your constructor and in most cases Laravel will automatically resolve and inject it into you class.

See the [Service Provider documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container) for some examples and alternatives.

To go with your example:

```php
class Bar {
    private $myClass;

    public function __construct(MyClass $myClass) {
       $this->myClass = $myClass;
    }
}
```

In cases where `Bar::__construct` takes other parameters that can not be per-defined in a service provider you will have to use a service locator:

```php
/* $this->app is an instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application */
$bar = new Bar($this->app->make(MyClass::class), /* other parameters */);
```

Alternatively, move the service location into the constructor it self:

```php
use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Bar {
    private $myClass;

    public function __construct() {
       $this->myClass = App::make(MyClass::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is how will I create multiple instances of Bar (especially if I have more parameters on the constructor).  i.e. `$bar = new Bar(5, 10);`. Updated question to show what I mean

Answer (score 2):

You can use singleton running `make` method of Application this way:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;

class Bar {
   private $myClass;
   private $a;
   private $b;

   public function __construct($a, $b, Application $app) {
      $this->a = $a;
      $this->b = $b;
      $this->myClass = $app->make(MyClass::class);
   }
}
```

You can read more about this in [Container resolving documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#resolving).

Comment: How would I create multiple different instances of `Bar`?

Comment: Also is there a way to access the `$app` variable in a static context

Comment: @YahyaUddin We were not talking about `Bar`. You can create instances of it using again `App::make(Bar::class)`. Instead of injecting `Application` you can use anywhere `App` facade, so you can run anywhere `App::make(SomeClass::class)` to create object (it will be either new instance or same instance depending whether it's defined as singleton or not).